# Is a finite semigroup having left cancellation property necessarily a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, semigroups

Is only left cancellation sufficient for a finite semigroup to be a group. 
Please give proof or counterexample.

Comment: This is the text of your homework. Now, the classical question: what have you done on your own? We help those that begin by helping themselves...

Comment: No its not in my homework, this question come in my thinking naturally. I tried hard but all times its need both side cancellation.  I don't put my trying here because I am new to stack and I  am not use to there complicated typing format.

Comment: All right. Have a look at (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancellative_semigroup).

Comment: I have taken the liberty to modify your title in order that subsequent searches are fruitful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S$ be any nonempty set, and define $xy=y$ for all $x,y\in S.$ Clearly the associative law holds: $(xy)z=z$ and $x(yz)=yz=z.$ The left cancellation property is even easier: $ax=ay\implies x=ax=ay=y.$ However, if $S$ has more than one element, it is not a group. So, to get a counterexample for your question, take $S=\{a,b\}$ with $aa=ba=a$ and $ab=bb=b.$